# ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis when adding constraints in create table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE S_Subject(
  subCode    VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
  title      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT subject_pk PRIMARY KEY (subCode),
  CONSTRAINT subject_uk UNIQUE KEY (title)
);
```

I have put all the values in for VARCHAR2 and used what I think the correct parethesis is. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: why downvotes on this question, except for code formatting it looks good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE S_Subject(
  subCode    VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
  title      VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT subject_pk PRIMARY KEY (subCode),
  CONSTRAINT subject_uk UNIQUE (title)
);
```

The `KEY` in `UNIQUE KEY` is excessive, Oracle is expecting `(` right after the `UNIQUE` keyword. That is why it is giving "missing left parenthesis" message.

Check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb0742/4

Comment: why -1? it seems to me that the answer is correct. Can you explain why downvote?

Comment: I thought I upvoted you I tried changing it but it said I am a new user and my votes wont count till I have a better rating I didn't downvote you to my knowledge.

Comment: @Mo920192 np, hope that it get's resolved. -1 looks bad :-(